# Pinpointing which public SSL cert is being used by REST endpoint

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, jks

I have one webapp that I am running on Tomcat in two environments, Dev and Test.  The apps are identical, but the server config and security levels are not.  The webapp connects to a an external customer's REST endpoint over https, which they have secured using a public cert.  Same endpoint in both environments.

The Dev app works fine, the Test app fails with this:

```
SSLHandshakeException ... Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

When I curl the endpoint, I see the customer is using a public certificate.  I assume that the version of the cert I have in my Dev server is up to date, and my Test server is expired.  However, when I examine the two servers' cacerts files in KeyStore Explorer, I don't find the cert at all.

I assume I just do not know how to find the relationship between a specific cert and its parent (parent cert?  global cert?).  So, either via commands or code, how do I find which entry in my Dev cacerts file represents the cert from the endpoint?

Comment: *The webapp connects to a client's REST endpoint over https...*   You seem to be using the words "client" and "server" with their meaning swapped, and this is confusing me. A server listens for connections, a client initiates connections. Is TLS client authentication involved here?

Comment: I mean "client" as in a customer of our company.

Comment: Yes, the point of PKI is that you don't need to, and don't, individually trust the certificates of other systems, but instead the Certificate Authorities (CAs) that issue them. You can use `keytool -printcert -sslserver $host[:$port]` to see the chain the TLS-server (=endpoint) uses, and look at the `Owner:` and `Issuer:` of each cert in turn (#0, #1, etc). The last cert should either be or point to the root (or anchor) CA that you need to trust; if not the server is defective -- if on the public net, use `https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest` to test.

Comment: Adding: you can use the fingerprint shown for an actual root cert to see if that cert is in your cacerts as listed by `keystore -list -cacerts`, but for a pointed-to one you'll need to look at the 'owner' (subject) name.